# SwiftUI ScrollViewProxy.scrollTo doesn't work on dynamically populated List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a dynamically populated `List` and a `TextField` in a SwiftUI view. When user is entering characters into the text view, I want to add each entered character into the list, and keep the list view scrolled to bottom, so the last entered character is visible.

However, for some reason, the `ScrollViewProxy`'s `scrollTo` method does nothing when list is dynamically populated.

Code to reproduce the issue:

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct RowItem: Equatable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var userInput = ""
 
    var convertedCharacters: [RowItem] {
        userInput.map {
            RowItem(value: String($0))
        }
    }

    // If I instead use a statically populated list, then scrollTo works as expected: 
    // var convertedCharacters: [RowItem] = (0..<100).map {
    //     RowItem(value: String($0))
    // }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                List(convertedCharacters) { i in
                    Text("Character: \(i.value)").id(i)
                }
                TextField("Enter a string", text: $userInput)
                    .onReceive(Just(userInput), perform: { _ in
                        // On user input change, scroll the list to bottom
                        proxy.scrollTo(convertedCharacters.last)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, when I enter enough characters so that the list grows past the bottom edge of the screen, it doesn't scroll to the last item.

However, if I were to populate the items statically (see commented out line where I instantiate `convertedCharacters`) then `scrollTo` suddenly works on every keystroke.

Why doesn't this work when list is dynamic? How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.onChange` instead of `.onReceive`

```
import SwiftUI

struct RowItem: Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: String
}

struct ProxyExample: View {
    
    @State private var userInput = ""
    @State private var convertedCharacters: [RowItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List {
                    ForEach(convertedCharacters, id: \.id) { i in
                        Text("Character: \(i.value)")
                            .id(i)
                    }
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            proxy.scrollTo(convertedCharacters.first)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        TextField("Enter a string", text: $userInput)
                            .onChange(of: userInput) { newValue in
                                let row = RowItem(value: newValue)
                                convertedCharacters.append(row)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```